# Use of acceleration in HTML <input type="number"> element

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am using an `<input type="number">` in association with a slider (`<input type="slider">`), to allow input for a large range of positive integers - say 10000-100000.

The slider moves in large steps, such as 5000. The user must be able to specify precise numbers in the input field, such as 4583.

I have trapped the slider's `oninput()` change so that the number is reflected in the number input element.

I have trapped the number field's `oninput()` change so that the number is reflected in the slider. This works when the user types into the field (although I have trapped values outside the slider's range) and *also* when using the up/down arrow keys.

The issue I have is with the up/down arrow keys. It would be nice, when the user holds the key down for more than a moment, for the rate of increase/decrease in the number change to increase.

This acceleration has been available on the Windows platform for many years via the [Up-Down control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/up-down-control-reference) (and in .NET's [Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netcore-3.1)), but I can't find any documentation for similar functionality in HTML (5). Does it exist? Is there a JavaScript library that provides it?

So far tested only on Chrome and Firefox and on each there is no acceleration, just a constant speed of increase.

Comment: "Does it exist? " - no, it does not. The DOM interface for the `HTMLInputElement` does not expose control over the up/down arrows buttons - that's because the specification for `<input type="number" />` does not define how browsers should present the input: having the up/down arrow buttons is an implementation concern.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using the `oninput=""` attribute to listen to events, you should use `addEventListener('input', func )` (the event's name is `input`, not `oninput` nor is it `oninput()`, and the term is "listen" not "trap" - this is because events in JavaScript are multiplexed and non-exclusive, whereas event systems that support "traps"/trapping imply they use exclusive handlers.

Comment: @Dai many thanks, I will follow up on your advice.